# tableHeaderView is overlapping cells when adding custom view to subview of container view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, nstableheaderview

I am currently using a `UIViewController` and adding a `UITableView` to the view. With this `tableView` I am adding a `UIView` called `containerView` to its `tableHeaderView`. I set the height of the container view and then adding a second `UIView` to its subview, that is pinned to the bottom of the `containerView`.

When I add it to the header view the cells are being overlapped. What's odd though is that if I don't add the subview to the container view the `headerView` is not being overlapped by the cells, it is only occurring when I am adding the second view as a subview to the container view.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var containerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.alpha = 0.7
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()

    private var bottomView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = .blue
        return view
    }()

    private(set) lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)

        containerView.addSubview(bottomView)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = containerView

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),

            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.topAnchor),
            containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 214),
            containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width),

            bottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            bottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 114),
            bottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.size.width),
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -view.safeAreaInsets.top, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.autoresizingMask = []
        tableView.tableHeaderView?.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Based on your code, it's not really clear exactly what you're trying to do... Do you want a table header view with something in the "red rectangle" and something else in the "blue rectangle", for example? If so, you need to setup your constraints differently, and there's no need for any `tableView.contentInset` values...

Comment: Yes, the red rectangle will have content inside it, and the the blue rectangle will just be an empty UIView, I made blue for this example to showcase that it is overlapping the cells. This view is to add some spacing between the cell below and the header view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your "blue view" is overlapping the cells is because you are constraining its Top to the red view's Bottom, but you're not updating the header view size.

One good approach is to create a `UIView` subclass to use as your header view. Setup all of its content with proper auto-layout constraints.

Then, in the controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`, we use `.systemLayoutSizeFitting(...)` to determine the header view's height and update its frame:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    
    // update table header size

    guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else { return }
    
    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow).height
    
    var frame = headerView.frame
    
    // avoids infinite loop!
    if height != frame.height {
        frame.size.height = height
        headerView.frame = frame
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }
}
```

Here is a complete example...

First, our custom view class:

```
class SampleHeaderView: UIView {

    let redView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        return v
    }()
    let blueView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        return v
    }()
    let redTopLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    let redBottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()
    let multiLineLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        
        // all views will use auto-layout
        [redView, blueView, redTopLabel, redBottomLabel, multiLineLabel].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        // prevent label vertical compression
        [redTopLabel, redBottomLabel, multiLineLabel].forEach { v in
            v.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        }
        
        // add top and bottom labels to red view
        redView.addSubview(redTopLabel)
        redView.addSubview(redBottomLabel)

        // add multi-line label to blue view
        blueView.addSubview(multiLineLabel)
        
        // add red and blue views to self
        addSubview(redView)
        addSubview(blueView)

        // the following constraints need to have less-than required to avoid
        //  auto-layout warnings
        
        // blue view bottom to self
        let c1 = blueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0)
        
        // labels trailing contraints
        let c2 = redTopLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        let c3 = redBottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        let c4 = multiLineLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0)
        
        [c1, c2, c3, c4].forEach { c in
            c.priority = .required - 1
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // red view top to self
            redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // leading / trailing to self
            redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // blue view top to red view bottom
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            //  leading / trailing to self
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // top and bottom labels, constrained in red view
            //  with a little "padding"
            redTopLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            redTopLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            redBottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redTopLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            redBottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),

            redBottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: redView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // multi-line label, constrained in blue view
            //  with a little "padding"
            multiLineLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            multiLineLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            multiLineLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // the less-than-required priority constraints
            c1, c2, c3, c4,

        ])
        
    }
}
```

and a sample controller:

```
class TableHeaderViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var sampleHeaderView = SampleHeaderView()
    
    private(set) lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        sampleHeaderView.redTopLabel.text = "The Red Top Label"
        sampleHeaderView.redBottomLabel.text = "The Red Bottom Label, with enough text that is should wrap."
        sampleHeaderView.multiLineLabel.text = "This text is for the Label in the Blue View. It is also long enough that it will require word-wrapping. Note that the header updates itself when the frame changes, such as on device rotation."
        tableView.tableHeaderView = sampleHeaderView

    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        // update table header size

        guard let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView else { return }
        
        let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: tableView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required, verticalFittingPriority: .defaultLow).height
        
        var frame = headerView.frame
        
        // avoids infinite loop!
        if height != frame.height {
            frame.size.height = height
            headerView.frame = frame
            tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        }
    }
    
}

extension TableHeaderViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let c = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        c.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath)"
        return c
    }
    
}
```

Output:

[image]

and rotated:

[image]

Comment: Marking as approved answer! Thanks for help